# Sending a proper message back to the IP from where the request was made?

Tags: c#, browser

I want to implement this stuff in my c# site. When somebody hits my URL(given) I do processing in my code behind page, whatever required. If everything is right processing is completed, but if not then I want to send a message to the IP from where the request has come.

My code example

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //Fetching IP 
    String ip = Convert.ToString(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
        ip = Convert.ToString(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
    else
        ip = ip.Split(',').Last().Trim();

    //Checking existence of IP in DB 
    DataTable IPcheck = MyStoredProcedure.GetList("WhiteListedIP", "*", "IP='" + ip + "' ");

    if (IPcheck.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        // My Actual Processing
    }
    else    // if IP doesn't exist in DB... 
    {
        // send msg of "IP doesn't exist" back 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are on a `Page`, you don't send messages somewhere. You display text to the user.

Comment: @Serv I am implementing this page as a callback url page.. i have created one url, and the user will hit that url (automatically on regular interval on his/her side) for some service which i'm providing... then i have to send him back msg.... is der any modification posible or my way is fine.. ?